# Constructing working ELF binary from memory dump

Tags: linux, debugging, binary, reverse-engineering, elf

I've written the following simple C program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello\n");
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling I load this program in GDB and continue as follows

```
> catch syscall brk  
*run and wait for GDB to catch syscall*
> info proc mappings

Start Addr    End Addr    Size    Offset    
0x8000000     0x8001000   0x1000  0x0       <--- this region is r-xp, so this is the code in memory
0x8200000     0x8202000   0x2000  0x0       <--- this region is rw-p, so this is the data in memory
> dump binary memory testdump 0x8000000 0x8001000
```

(the reason I set a catchpoint on brk is because this syscall is called before execution of the program, but with the program loaded in memory)

Using *readelf* on the memory dump gives the following output

```
$ readelf -h testdump
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x530
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6440 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 28
readelf: Error: Reading 1856 bytes extends past end of file for section headers
readelf: Error: Section headers are not available!
```

I was wondering how I can fix these errors and make an executable ELF binary from this memory dump which runs the same as the original program. Note that I want to do this with just a hexeditor (e.g. *hexedit*) and without using the original binary.

Answer (score 0):

> `dump binary memory testdump 0x8000000 0x8001000`

To make a runnable program, you would also need to dump the data.

Your test binary is dynamically-linked, which complicates your task significantly. I suggest starting from a fully-static binary.

> I want to do this with just a hexeditor

This task is actually not trivial, and I doubt you'll be able to accomplish it with GDB.

Comment: And If the binary is statically linked how can I fix the errors in my original post and make an executable ELF binary from this memory dump which runs the same as the original program?

Comment: I don't believe you can. I think that it's impossible to do this in GDB.